# What is the difference between execute-dir: <project|file> in quarto

Tags: quarto

The documentation for the project options in quarto states:

> execute-dir    Control the working directory for computations.
>
> file: Use the directory of the file that is currently executing.
> project: Use the root directory of the project.

But I can't figure out what these two options actually do. For example, I have a file file called /Users/benc/projects/ms2/src/poc/quarto/execute-dir_test.qmd with contents:

````
---
title: "execute-dir test"
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
project:
  execute-dir: project
---

```{r}
#| results: asis

cat(getwd())

```
````

When I click "Render" in rstudio, this produces an html file with the contents:

`/Users/benc/projects/ms2/src/poc/quarto`

If I change the above code to: `execute-dir: project` the result is exactly the same

`/Users/benc/projects/ms2/src/poc/quarto`

I would have thought this would be

`/Users/benc/projects/ms2`

which is where the .rproj file is stored.